# Access AWS RDS from local machine without EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is it possible to directly connect to RDS from a local Machine without EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do that but for that you would have to make the RDS publicly accessible and make sure that the whichever security group RDS is in, it allows the inbound connections.

[image]

Comment: I gave access to all traffic but still not able to access it, but it's connecting from EC2.

Comment: Is your database publicly accessible? You can check that in Connectivity tab.

Comment: Yes, my database is publicly accessible.

Comment: You RDS instance might be in private subnet. Have you verified that?

Comment: I have one public subnet associated with RDS

Comment: I had other two subnets, which are private. Editing the route table to normal internet gateway solved the problem.